# Entity-Component System: Multiple different geometries on one entity

Tags: entity, components, system

I am writing 3D geometry visualization software for schools. I am designing my engine as an Entity-Component system, because it has served me well in games. In this case I have some specific requirements:

- There is a limited amount of different geometries I need to render. I would like to render these in batches. So I render all lines as one batch, all triangles as one batch, all planes as one batch, ... It works well even with transparent objects, since I am using depth peeling and don't need to sort them by distance.
- One logical object will typically have more than one mesh associated: e.g. a plane entity has a border "child"-entity that has four lines as its body, these lines all share the same material.
- I would like to have a clean design, so I am trying to stay true to the *no-code-in-components* principle and *same-structure* for one type of components.

What I have now is: A different component type for each type of geometry (point, line, plane, ...). The corresponding system stores a batch with a mesh + instance data and renders it in one draw call. The instance data for different types of geometry is different, hence I decided to go with one component type per geometry type. (A bad design?)

**Question**:
Now I'm wondering how to handle entities that seem to need multiple components of the same type, like the plane border, that has a body consisting of four lines.

I could think of several solutions, which all have draw-backs:

**1.** Make each line of the border entity an entity itself. Each would have a "line" component and a "child" component. That would model the border and the lines as five entities, with the four lines attached to the border entity via "child" component. This seems like quite a waste of entities. Some special entities would have several dozens of children then.

**2.** Allow the border entity to have multiple components of the "line" type. This seems like a hack, since all ECS article I've seen discourage using multiple components of the same type on one entity.

**3.** Make a unified "geometry" component that may contain an arbitrary number of elementary geometries. That would introduce quite some indirections, but seems like the best solution to me, at the moment.

Could someone help me to sort this chaotic thoughts into a good solution? I'm sure I'm missing a straight-forward approach, but I just couldn't find one yet.

I have a lot of experience in programming (10+ years), but unfortunately, just recently started with Entity-Component systems. So I'm still struggling with the concept, it seems.

Thank you very much.